# Is there a ML model that can determine the sequence that leads to an outcome?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a problem where a certain sequence of events leads to a certain outcome.  The problem is, I am not sure exactly what the sequence is.  I am hoping to get some possible sequences to test as opposed to analyzing the events one by one.

Is there a ML technique that can allow me to determine the sequence of predictors that allow me to predict a response?  It's pretty easy to put in a bunch of raw features and see which ones matter, but when it comes to a sequence of features, I am not sure what to do.

The goal here is not only prediction, but also interpretation in that I need to know what features and what sequences matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Would something like this make sense?  Instead of trying to determine the sequence all at once, just build several models, one that predicts the next.  So build a model that predicts T0 with T-1.  Then build a model that predicts T-1 with T-2.  Etc...  I think this is what I'll attempt unless there's a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in a particular kind of neural network designed for sequential tasks: [rnn](/questions/tagged/rnn)s come in several flavors, including [lstm](/questions/tagged/lstm) and [gru](/questions/tagged/gru) networks which have been used to model long sequences such as natural language. This can be used to generate $n$-step ahead predictions; in the natural language setting, this can be used to do stuff like writing novel tweets.

Comment: Thanks.  This would be preferred to a convolution neural network?

Comment: RNNs and CNNs are not mutually exclusive. Anyway, which model does best for some particular problem probably depends on the problem.